# Find connected elements from columns in file

Tags: qt

I have a list of some components, say with IDs 1 to 140.
I have a table in excel with two columns of data as follows:

```
I/p O/p
-------------
38  1
1   5
1   3
76  1
77  1
78  1
79  1
77  2
78  2
79  2
125 126
22  126
23  126
113 127
113 134
113 135
113 136
```

and so on. I have more than 5000 rows in the table.

I need to compute the number of components to which each component is connected. Say component 1 could be an input or an output, I need to find the total number of components 1 is connected to. From the example above, 1 is connected to 7 components in total, 38, 5, 3, 76, 77, 78, 79.

How should I do it programmatically with Qt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example it seems as if the order of the values is not important.  E.g. a line containing

```
76 1
```

seems to be the same as

```
1 76
```

(at least for what you want to do with it).

Easiest seems to be to set up a multimap and add all pairs to it (twice because the order is not important).  E.g.

```
std::multi_map<int,int> values;

while (reading a line)
   {
   int firstValue = first value found on line;
   int secondValue = second value found on line;
   values.insert(std::make_pair(firstValue,secondValue));
   }
```

When you want to know all values connected to a value, just look it up in the multi_map:

```
int valueToSearchFor = ...;
auto range = values.equal_range(valuetoSearchFor);
while (range.first!=range.second)
   {
   std::cout << range.first->second << std::endl;
   ++range.first;
   }
```

Notice that the multi_map might contain duplicates (if the same pairs appear in the input file).  To solve this, either build up an std::set while looping over the range and skip values that you already encountered before, or use the following data structure instead:

```
std::map<int,std::set<int>>
```

Remember that different data structures will have different impact on memory and CPU usage so you might want to refine the data structure for your own specific use.

If you want to also know all indirectly connected values, build up a vector with all values that you encounter and iterate over it while you are looping over it (and also use an std::set to prevent using the same value over and over again).  E.g.

```
std::set<int> alreadyEncounteredValues;
std::vector<int> foundValues;
valueToSearchFor = ...;
foundValues.push_back(valueToSearchFor);
alreadyEncounteredValues.insert(valueToSearchFor);
for (size_t index=0;index<foundValues.size();++index)
   {
   auto thisValueToSearchFor = foundValues[index];
   for (auto range=values.equal_range(thisValueToSearchFor);range.first!=range.second;++range.first)
      {
      auto foundValue = range.first->second;
      auto insertResult = alreadyEncounteredValues.insert(foundValue);
      if (!insertResult.second)
         {
         // We already encountered this value.  Skip it.
         continue;
         }
      // New value
      foundValues.push_back(foundValue);
      }
   }
```

With this method, we insert all found values in the set (to make it easy to see if we already encountered the value) and in the vector.  We also loop over the vector so we will also look up all indirectly linked values.  After a while the index will catch up with the size and we know we found all indirectly linked values.

Comment: I'm afraid I did not quite follow from the range part. I have "values" with all the entries. I am now looping from 1 to 140 and in this loop I am trying to know the connected values and store it (not output the values) remove duplicates. How do I use equal_range in Qt?

Comment: I suggest to use standard STL containers instead of the Qt containers.  std::multi_map has an equal_range method (the values variable refers to the std::multi_map that I filled in the first code example).